# Regex expression has me stumped

Tags: c#, regex

Hi trying to work out a regex problem

I have a formula parser that needs to get the strings within some tags, the input string will look like this:

```
[//part1/part2/abc]+[/def]+[ghi]
```

All I want returned is three groups like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

I have a partially working regex that gets me three groups, and the strings between the square brackets, but I just can't get rid of the prefixed path.

If there is a path, it will always use forward slashes.

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Would `\[.*?\/?([^\/\]]+)\]` be sufficient? [Here it is in action](http://www.regexr.com/390ul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below regex to capture one or more word characters before the `]` bracket,

```
(\w+)\]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wA7zE1)

Comment: @raydeni Nothing wrong with Avinash's answer as long as you know what you're buying: for instance it won't work with `[/a-1]` or `[/a&1]` but it will match `no_opening_bracket]` Nothing wrong with that if that's okay with your input, just be aware of it. :)

Comment: Yes, the tags are limited to [A-Za-z0-9], so it should work fine. I should have stated that.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
@"\[(?:[^]/]*/)*([^]/]+)]"
```

Where the optional non capturing group will match all that ends with a slash.

Comment: Nearly identical to mine, but with capture group instead of lookbehind... +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

**Direct Match (No Capture)**

This regex is a bit more complex because rather than capturing what you want to Group 1, we are matching it directly.

The regex also validates that we are inside the `[brackets]`:

```
(?x)                # free-spacing mode
(?<=                # look behind: we should see
\[                  # an opening bracket, then
(?:(?:[^/\]]*/+)+)? # optionally, one or more series of 
                    # non-slashes, non-closing brackets followed by slashes
)                   # end lookbehind
[^/\]]*             # this is what we want to match: any character that is not a / or a ]
(?=[^/]*\])         # lookahead: we should see no slashes, then a closing ]
```

See [demo](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=5c707009-f54f-422c-8055-cf814fa11a80).

You can actually use it in this free-spacing mode, which makes it easy to maintain and understand later. The explanation is in the comments.

**In C# code:**

Here is one way to use this regex in C#:

```
Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"(?x) #free-spacing mode
(?<=                # look behind: we should see
\[                  # an opening bracket, then
(?:(?:[^/\]]*/+)+)? # optionally, one or more series of 
                    # non-slashes, non-closing brackets followed by slashes
)                   # end lookbehind
[^/\]]*             # this is what we want to match: any character that is not a / or a ]
(?=[^/]*\])         # lookahead: we should see no slashes, then a closing ]
");

allMatchResults = yourRegex.Matches(yourstring);
if (allMatchResults.Count > 0) {
 // Access individual matches using allMatchResults.Item[]
}
```

Comment: Hurts my head looking at it, but works well. What's the disadvantage of using capturing groups?